# Output of numbers in R notebook

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr, rnotebook

I have a question concerning outputting numbers inline in a R notebook.
I wanted to switch to a more readable code using dplyr and pipes, but now the numbers I would like to compute are no longer shown in line with the text.

So far, I wrote my code like this:

```
Number of dogs: `r nrow(animals[which(animals$species == "dog"),])`!
```

And I got the numbers inline:

```
Number of dogs: 8!
```

If I switch to

```
Number of dogs: `r animals %>% filter(species == "dog") %>% count()`!
```

The output is no longer inline, but inserted in the line below, with a box around it:

```
Number of dogs:
[              n]
[          <int>]
[             90]
[1 row          ]
!
```

How do I get the inline output back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is coerced to a `tibble`.

```
library(dplyr)

(xy <- iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa") %>% count())

# A tibble: 1 × 1
      n
  <int>
1    50
```

Wrap it into `as.numeric` to get a single digit (vector of length 1).

```
> as.numeric(xy)
[1] 50
```

`unlist(xy)` also works.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how the OP did the coding

---

````
title: "Testing"
author: "akrun"
date: "April 28, 2017"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
```

```{r code1, eval=TRUE, echo = FALSE}

animals <- data.frame(species = c("dog", "cat", "dog", "cat"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
animals1 <- data_frame(species = c("dog", "cat", "dog", "cat"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
animals2 <- as_tibble(animals)
```


Number of dogs: `r animals %>% filter(species == "dog") %>% count()`!

Number of dogs: `r animals1 %>% filter(species == "dog") %>% count()`!

Number of dogs: `r animals2 %>% filter(species == "dog") %>% count()`!
````

gives the output

[image]